# How to use QTextStream with PythonQT?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtextstream, pythonqt

I am writing a plugin for a Qt desktop app using PythonQT.
I wonder how to use << operator in python.

```
QTextStream stream(&file);
stream << doc.toString();
```

Any hints?
How may I ask Python to list all methods for a given class like QTextStream?
Or is there another way in Python to write a QDomDocument to a QFile?

Comment: I think it should be the same, have you tried?

Comment: Yes, its not working...

Comment: You could show what you've tried.

Comment: stream << doc.toString()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'QTextStream' and 'unicode'

Comment: But this is working :-)

 stream = QTextStream(xmlfile)
 doc.save(stream, 0)

Comment: You could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44417017/edit) your question and add what you have tried.

Comment: You could share your code through github, drive, dropbox or similar to better understand your question

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution already...

```
doc = QDomDocument()
root = doc.createElement("Animation")
doc.appendChild(root)
stream = QTextStream(xmlfile)
doc.save(stream, 0)
```